# Python 3 py2exe no module tkinter._fix

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, py2exe

I'm trying to make an exe file from my code. but py2exe gives an error like this:

> import tkinter._fix as fix
>   ImportError: No module named 'tkinter._fix'

my setup.py file is like this

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(console=['userInterface.py'], options={
                'py2exe': {
                    'includes': ['tkinter']
                }
        })
```

I'm using python 3.5 32bit

Answer (score 0):

py2exe runs on python 3.4. I think this will work if you downgrade your version of python. Alternatively, you can use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to compile your python windows application into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter._fix was removed after python 3.5. And py2exe for support python 3.6+ is here: https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe